# How do I animate efficiently with poor frame rate?

Tags: animation, frame-rate

I often have large scenes, with maybe 25,000 objects, for example. I have always had the problem of poor frame rate when animating the scene, or even the camera. I'm using a very fast and up to date system. It's essentially impossible to do motion graphics without continually needing to *viewport render animation*. I don't often use subsurf, so that's not something I can suppress. The *frame dropping* function in playback may raise the fps a tiny bit, but not much. I often need to match music or narration to the camera so I need something that works exactly at the desired fps. Even a small scene, with many instances or particles, will cause this problem.

This must be a common problem, and I wonder what you all are doing about it.

Comment: in render settings, you can check simplify and play with values under viewport, you can downsize the number of instances + particles, you could partially hide objects via GN or other tools, you could use camera LOD ....and others